# Explain an example for a midterm C++

Tags: c++

My teacher just gave this as one of several program examples for an upcoming midterm in C++.  The code is:

```
//What does this program print?

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define foo1( a )  a * a

int j = 6;

inline  int
foo2( int a ) 
{
    return a * a;
}

void
goo1( int& x )
{
    x = 3;
}

void
goo2( int  x )
{
    x = 3;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j = 12;

    cout << "foo1 = " << foo1( 3 + 2 ) << "\n";
    cout << "foo2 = " << foo2( 3 + 2 ) << "\n";

    i = 5;
    goo1( i );
    cout << "goo1 = " << i << "\n";
    i = 5;
    goo2( i );
    cout << "goo2 = " << i << "\n";

    cout << "  j = " <<   j << "\n";
    cout << "::j = " << ::j << "\n";
}
```

Can someone please explain how foo1 = 11.  I've been experimenting with different numbers for an hour and I can't understand exactly how that is calculated.

Comment: During this hour you haven't done text substitution of the macro with its definition, which is what you should do in the first second some teacher or job interviewer asks you about a macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

foo1 is a macro.  Macros perform strict find and replace, so foo1(3+2) is replaced with 3+2*3+2.
Following order of operations, 3+2*3+2 = 3+6+2 = 11.

Comment: Oh, it seems so obvious now.  Thank you so much, I've been reading on pre-processor stuff for a while and couldn't make heads or tales of it.

Answer (score 2):

you have

```
#define foo1( a )  a * a
```

So when you say`foo1( 3 + 2 )`, compiler sees `3 + 2 * 3 + 2`. obviously `11`

If you want the macro `foo1` to do multiplication, you should

```
#define foo1(a) ((a)*(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the macro gets pounded out to be this:

```
cout << "foo1 = " << 3 + 2 * 3 + 2 << "\n";
```

And simple BODMAS tells me that that is equal to 11 :) i.e.
`3 + (2 * 3) + 2`

Answer (score 0):

foo1 is a macro defined as  `foo1(a) a * a`.

all `#define` statements are C-preprocessor macro statements. They are literally expanded into the code BEFORE any compilation takes place.

So

```
#define foo1(a) a * a
```

changes

```
cout << "foo1 = " << foo1( 3 + 2 ) << "\n";
```

to

```
cout << "foo1 = " << 3 + 2 * 3 + 2 << "\n";
```

Since there are no parentheses around a in the expansion the evaluation is 11

If you want to see it work the way you expected it to (i.e. end up being 25) you can experiment with the define as under:

```
#define foo1(a) (a) * (a)
```

and you will see it ends up being 25

Also you should be able to just see the preprocessor output by using the correct compiler options. For gcc or g++ it's  -E  ...

Hope you have fun with it

Answer (score 0):

Function-like macros work by  [direct text substitution](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html)

So `foo1(3+2)` becomes `(3 + 2*3 + 2)` which is 11